# Excel VBA wildcard search

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I currently have an Excel file with 1 column and many rows. The column holds a first name, last name, and possibly a middle name (EXAMPLE: John Abe Smith). I am writing a macro that has 1 textbox and 1 button. In the excel sheet I have a couple names:

```
Column A
--------
John Abe Smith
Cindy Troll Bee
Randy Row
Joe Jumbo
Katie Kool Kat
```

I want to write a macro that when I type something in the textbox and click the button, it will look in this column for the name. If it finds it, then just say "found" in a message box.

I want to use the wildcard "*" when searching the names, but I do not know how. I currently have some code like this, but the wildcard does not work:

```
Private Sub search_Click()
    For firstloop = 3 To 10
        If Range("G" & firstloop).Text = name.Text & "*" Then
            MsgBox "Found!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "NOT FOUND"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

For example, let's say I type in "*Troll*" in the text box and I click the button. I want the loop to go through the column to find anything with "Troll" in it. The result from the example data would be just `Cindy Troll Bee`.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator (*case-sensitive*):

```
Private Sub search_Click()
    For firstloop = 3 To 10
        If Range("G" & firstloop).Text Like name.Text & "*" Then
            MsgBox "Found!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "NOT FOUND"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

for *case-insensitive* search use:

```
If UCase(Range("G" & firstloop).Text) Like UCase(name.Text) & "*" Then
```

Also if you want to determine whether cell *contains* text (not only *starts* with text), you can use (*case-sensitive*):

```
If InStr(1, Range("G" & firstloop).Text, name.Text) > 0 Then
```

or (*case-insensitive*)

```
If InStr(1, Range("G" & firstloop).Text, name.Text, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

**UPD:**

If the point only to show `msgbox`, then I'd suggest to use `Application.Match`:

```
Private Sub search_Click()
    If Not IsError(Application.Match("abc" & "*", Range("G3:G10"), 0)) Then
        MsgBox "Found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "NOT FOUND"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts, you're welcome:) also if the point of your macro only to show message box, I'd suggest you to use `Application.Match` instead loop. See my updated answer

Comment: "Option Compare Text" can be used instead of  UCase

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid a loop and use the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) Method. You can pass as option if you want it case sensitive or not. (By default it is not case sensitive.)

```
Set rngFound= Range("G" & firstloop).Find(name.Text & "*") 
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found!"
Else           
    MsgBox "FOUND"
End If
```