# IF statement not being evaluated correctly excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find files with specific text in the file name and run a macro on only those.  Everything is fantastic but the IF statement that is supposed to pick out the specific files isn't evaluating correctly. I can see the file name stored in the variable, I've even tried converting the variable from a variant to a string - but the IF statement doesn't seem to be reading the name.  It runs the macro on all files in the folder.

---

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Folder
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim file As String

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files

            file = myFile.Name

            If file <> "*CONSOLIDATED SUMMARY.xls*" Then
                Application.Workbooks.Open fileName:=myFile
                Call UnmergeAndResize
                ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        Next
        Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.path)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087446/excel-vba-wildcard-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `*` character to perform partial string matches in VBA.

Instead, you should replace the line containing the `If` statement with:

```
    If InStr(file, "CONSOLIDATED SUMMARY.xls") = 0 Then
```

Comment: If that solves your problem, it would be much appreciated if you could mark the answer as accepted.