# Searching an Excel column for containing text

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that searches excel files. I have it currently working, but I want to see how I can do a search for contains, not just the value.

Example:

Cell C1: UCS
Cell C2: UCS1

It will only find the one in cell C1

```
Dim UCS As String = "UCS"
    If rng.Cells(i).value = UCS Then

    End If
```

Comment: Simple: use the `like` operator or `Instr()` in your function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087446/excel-vba-wildcard-search

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for that link, looking at it now. Having some trouble with it due to I do not know what some of his strings are doing.