# MsgBox value that starts with 4 above found value.

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm running a macro to find customer in raw data. Sheet 1 is customer list and sheet 2 is a lot of raw data. In the loop there is a `MsgBox` that shows if there is a customer in data. The data looks something like this:

[image]

How do i get `MsgBox` to show first value that starts with 4.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
Public Sub TestMe()

Dim r1      As Variant
Dim r2      As Variant
Dim r3      As Variant

Dim rData   As Variant
Dim r       As Variant
Dim result  As Variant

rData = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(2).Range("A:A"))

r1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C2:C33"))
r2 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C34:C35"))
r3 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("C36:C43"))


For Each r In r1
    result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        MsgBox r
    End If
Next r

For Each r In r2
    result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        MsgBox r
    End If
Next r

For Each r In r3
    result = Application.Match(r, rData, 0)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        MsgBox r
    End If
Next r


MsgBox "search ended."

End Sub
```

Comment: Related: [Excel VBA wildcard search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087446/excel-vba-wildcard-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim bigRange    As Range
    Dim myCell      As Range

    Set bigRange = Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A9")
    For Each myCell In bigRange
        If Left(myCell, 1) = 4 Then
            MsgBox myCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

It will simply loop through the cells in the `bigRange` and check whether the first character of the cell is `4`. If it is `4`, it shows the `MsgBox` and it exits the loop.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak  - in my code change `A1:A9` to `C2:C33`. Then copy the code 2 more times, changing further to `C34:C35` and to `C36:C43`.

Comment: but how do i set it in way that `MsgBox` will show `r` from original loop and the `myCell` in the same box?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something along these lines.  At a high level the code loops cell in the 1st column of your first sheet, to extract the customer ids.  Each id is searched for in the second sheet.  If found we work our way up (using the [offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) looking for a cell starting 4.

```
Sub findCustomer()
    Dim customerWs As Worksheet         ' Ref to the customer worksheet.
    Dim rawWs As Worksheet              ' Ref to the raw worksheet.
    Dim currentCustomer As Range        ' Used to loop over all customers.
    Dim findCustomer As Range           ' Used to search raw for current customer.
    Dim offsetRow As Integer            ' Used to search above found customer for value starting 4.

    Set customerWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rawWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' Assumes all customer ids are located in the first column
    ' of sheet 1.
    ' Loop executed once for each cell in that column.
    For Each currentCustomer In customerWs.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells

        ' Look for the current customer.
        Set findCustomer = rawWs.Columns(1).Find(currentCustomer.Value)
        If Not findCustomer Is Nothing Then

            ' Found one.
            ' Work up one row at a time looking for 4.
            For offsetRow = 1 To (findCustomer.Row - 1)

                If findCustomer.Offset(offsetRow * -1, 0).Value Like "4*" Then

                    ' Match found.
                    ' Inform user and exit.
                    MsgBox "Customer: " & findCustomer.Value & ". 4 Found: " & findCustomer.Offset(offsetRow * -1, 0).Address & "."
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```